# Adding assembler directives

Tags: assembly, directive, src

I am new to SRC assembly and I was wondering how to write the SRC assembly language program to evaluate the following expression.
X = 4(7+c) – 8*d + 64(21+e)
Where c=11, d=17 and e= 23
Note: X, c, d and e are memory labels

I have done the following work but don't know how to define memory labels by using assembler directives. Somebody please tell me how to write pseudo op-codes for memory labels?

```
ld R1,e
addi R3,R1,21
shl R4,R3,6
ld R5,d
shl R6,R5,3
add R7,R6,R4
ld R8,c
addi R9,R8,7
shl R10,R9,2
st R10,X
```

Comment: In most assembly language syntaxes, you'd define `e` by putting `e:` at the start of a line, or on a line by itself.  I don't know what directive/pseudo-instruction SRC uses to assemble numeric data into the output, though.

Comment: I know that stuff already. I am looking for pseudo op-codes.

Comment: First I've heard of the 'SRC' assembler.  Is that [this](https://github.com/KyleLavorato/Simple-RISC-Computer)?  If so, they provide the source code to their assembler.  It's a 167 line python program.  I see no pseudo ops defined.